# Use ? on &Result<T, String>

Tags: rust

Why am I getting this error and how to fix it?
This is how i got temp: `let temp = self.value.clone().iter().map(|x| self.parse(x.to_string())).collect::<Vec<Result<T, String>>>();` 
Its just parsing a String to T. That works fin.

```
Ok(temp.iter().map(|x: &Result<T, String> | x?).collect::<Vec<T>>())
```

```
the `?` operator cannot be applied to type `&Result<T, String>`
    |
    = help: the trait `Try` is not implemented for `&Result<T, String>`
    = help: the trait `Try` is implemented for `Result<T, E>
```

This is a fix that works, but the map above should work too.

```
let mut res = vec![];
        for v in temp {
            res.push(v?);
        }
        Ok(res)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `&`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 that'll yield "error[E0631]: type mismatch in closure arguments"

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0bf87349ad57a0dab6c06b0acce8fd32

Comment: My crystal ball says you probably want `Ok(temp.into_iter().collect::<Result<Vec<T>, String>>()?)`, though its hard to know for sure without a full example.

Answer (score 4):

You get this error because you cannot use `?` with references of `Result`s.

But what you've written doesn't work if you had `Result`s either, because the `?`-operator early returns from the inner most function (here the closure) instead you can turn the `&Result<T, String>` into `Result<&T, &String>` using `as_ref` and `collect` into a `Result`:

```rust
pub fn foo<T>(temp: &[Result<T, String>]) -> Result<Vec<&T>, String> {
    Ok(temp.iter().map(|x| x.as_ref()).collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?)
}
```

Comment: The Ok and ? seem pretty redundant here, given you are unwrapping and immediately rewrapping the same result type

Comment: It's not, `?` here converts the `&String` (which we have after `Result::as_ref`) into a proper `String`.